# Issue with the test results file and coverage file generated during Sonar Scan stage in Jenkins

Tags: .net, jenkins, groovy, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have a dotNet project that runs through Jenkins pipeline. What's happening is that, a new testresults (.trx) file and a new coverage (.coverage) file are getting generated for every job through Jenkins pipeline. I am unable to figure out how to include these dynamically generated paths in the groovy file for the analysis to take place. Right now what we did is we are hardcoding the paths of both the files that are generated during the previous job. But is there a way to use the same files, that are generated in a particular job, for the same job, instead of using the files from the previous one?

/d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=${vstestReportPaths} 
CoverageFile: coverageFile

I am using the above parameters in the groovy where vstestReportPaths and coverageFile represent the hardcoded values of the .trx file and .coverage file generated in the previous job.

Any help/lead could be very helpful.  We are using DotNet core, xUnit tests and generating the testresults using vstest.console.exe

Answer (score 0):

Use codecoverage.exe to generate .xml from .coverage. Then you can use .xml files in sonar scanner